# Factoring $x^4 - x^2 + 1$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

I'm interesting in finding the possible quadratic factorization of this polynomial: $x^4 - x^2 + 1$. My first idea was to do long division by $x^2+1$, but I did get a remainder, so I presume this doesn't have a quadratic factorization over $\mathbb{R}$.

How should I go about factoring the polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Try to do $X:=x^2$

Comment: $$x^4-x^2+1= (x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt3x)^2$$ or $$(x^2-1)^2-(ix)^2$$

Comment: Yes, this is the right way. $(x^2-\sqrt{3}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}x+1)$

Comment: Your equation is a particular [biquadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Biquadratic_equations).

Comment: See also: [Show that $x^4-x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2414579).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitute $y = x^2$; then you get $$y^2 - y + 1$$ which you can factor in the usual way (for example, with the quadratic formula) into something of the form $$(y-a)(y-b).$$   Then put back $x^2$: $$(x^2-a)(x^2-b)$$  and each of the two terms is a difference of squares.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
x^4-x^2+1&=(x^2+1)^2-3x^2\\
&=(x^2-\sqrt{3}\,x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{3}\,x+1)
\end{align}