# How to factor the polynomial $x^4-x^2 + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, factoring, quartics

How do I factor this polynomial: $$x^4-x^2+1$$
The solution is: $$(x^2-x\sqrt{3}+1)(x^2+x\sqrt{3}+1)$$
Can you please explain what method is used there and what methods can I use generally for 4th or 5th degree polynomials?

Comment: Specifically with the problem above, you could use the quadratic formula on $y^2-y+1$ where $y=x^2$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260803/62967

Comment: Sorry A6Tech for my unhelpful idea!

Comment: See also: [Factoring $x^4 - x^2 + 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726316)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first to try would be to look for (rational) roots, but that is fruitless here (you need only test divisors of the constant term, but $\pm1$ is not a root).

Next you might try to factor as $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+a'x+b')$ with integer  coefficients, where once again you could conclude that $bb'=1$, so $b=b'=\pm1$. However, as the solutionm tells as, this won't work to produce *integer* values $a,a'$ - though if you still give it a try with $b=b'=1$, you might be led to $a,a'=\pm\sqrt 3$.

However, a "trick" works here: Try to add something simple (that is also a easy to take the square root of) in order to obtain a square. Here we have $x^4-x^2+1$, which almost looks like $x^4+2x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2$, so we have 
$$ x^4-x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-3x^2 = (x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt3x)^2$$
and can apply the third binomial formula to obtain a factorization.

Answer (score 12):

**Key Idea** $\ $ **Completing the** $\rm\color{#0a0}{square}$ yields a **difference of squares**

$$\ \color{#c00}{2ab=c^2}\Rightarrow\!  \begin{eqnarray} \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{a^2+b^2}}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box\!\!} &\,=\,& \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(a+b)^2}}^{\rm\!\!\! completed\  \large \Box \!\!\!}-\ \overbrace{\color{#c00}{2ab}}^{\textstyle \color{#c00}{c^2}}\ \ \text{so factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\[.2em]
 &\,=\,& (a+b\color{#c00}\ \ {-\ \ \color{#c00}{c}})\ (a+b\, + \color{#c00}{c})\\
 \end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

$$\begin{eqnarray} \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^4+1}}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box\!\!}\!\! -x^2 &\,=\,& \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(x^2\!+1)^2}}^{\rm\!\!\! completed\  \large \Box \!\!\!}-\ \color{#c00}{3\, x^2}\ \ \text{so factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\[.2em]
 &\,=\,& (x^2+1\color{#c00}\ \ {-\ \ \color{#c00}{\sqrt3 x}})\ (x^2+1\, + \color{#c00}{\sqrt3 x})\\
 \end{eqnarray}$$
[Another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1171277/242)
$$\begin{eqnarray} \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{n^4+4k^4}}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box}\!\! &=\,& \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{(n^2\!+2k^2)^2}}^{\rm\!\!\! completed\ \large \Box\!\!\!}\!\!-\!(\color{#c00}{2nk})^2\ \ \text{so factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\[.2em]
 &\,=\,& (n^2\!+2k^2\ -\,\ \color{#c00}{2nk})\,(n^2\!+2k^2+\,\color{#c00}{2nk})\\[.2em]
&\,=\,&(\underbrace{(n-k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}\ +\ \,k^2)\ \ \underbrace{((n+k)^2}_{\rm\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! complete\ the\ square\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!} +\,k^2)\\ \end{eqnarray}$$
[Another example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3054137/242)
$$\begin{eqnarray}\overbrace{3^{\large 6}+1}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box\!\!}\!\!-\,3^{\large 3}&=\ &\! \overbrace{(3^{\large 3}+1)^{\large 2}}^{\rm\!\!\!\!\! completed\ \large \Box\!\!\!\!\!}\!\!-\color{#c00}{3\,3^{\large 3}}\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\[.3em]
 &\!\!\!=&\! (\underbrace{3^{\large 3}+1\,\ -\, \color{#c00}{3^{\large 2}}}_{\Large 19})\ (\underbrace{3^{\large 3}+1\ +\,\color{#c00}{3^2}}_{\Large 37})\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

Generally $\ a^{\large 6} + b\, a^{\large 3} + c^{\large 2}\,$ factors if $\ \color{#c00}{ b= 2c\!-\!ad^{\large 2}}$ for some $d\,$ (above is $\,a,b,c,d = 3,-1,1,1)$

$$\qquad\ \begin{eqnarray}\overbrace{a^{\large 6}+c^{\large 2}}^{\rm incomplete\ \large \Box\!\!}\!+b\,a^{\large 3}&=\ &\!\! \overbrace{(a^{\large 3}+c)^{\large 2}}^{\rm\!\!\!\!\! completed\ \large \Box\!\! \!\!\!}\!\!+\color{#c00}{\overbrace{(b-2c)}^{\!\!\large -d^{\Large 2}a}\,a^{\large 3}}\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\[.3em]
 &\!\!\!=&\! ({a^{\large 3}+c\,\ -\, \color{#c00}{da^{\large 2}}})\ ({a^{\large 3}+c\ +\,\color{#c00}{da^{\large 2}}})\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $ $ This [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) to completing a $\rm\color{#0a0}{product\ (rectangle)}$, via the [AC-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242), viz.

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&axy + bx + cy\, =\, d,\ \ a\ne 0\\
\overset{\times\,a}\iff\, &&\!\! (ax+c)(ay+b)\, =\, ad+bc\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21259/242) for a generalizations - (*Aurifeuillian*) factorizations of cyclotomic polynomials, having the form $\rm\;\Phi_n(x) = C_n(x)^2 - n\ x\  D_n(x)^2,\,$ e.g. below.

$$\begin{align}
x^4 + 2^2 &=  (x^2 + 2x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 2) \\[.3em]
{x^6 + 3^3} &=  (x^2 + 3x + 3)(x^2 - 3x + 3)(x^3+3) \\[.3em]
 {x^{10} - 5^5} &=  (x^4 + 5x^3 + 15x^2 + 25x + 25)(x^4 - 5x^3 + 15x^2 - 25x + 25)(x^2-5)\\[.3em]
{x^{12} + 6^6} &=  (x^4 + 6x^3 + 18x^2 + 36x + 36)\;(x^4 - 6x^3 + 18x^2 - 36x + 36)(x^4 + 36)
\end{align}$$

Comment: always answers well wrote and well explained using colors

Comment: The latter factorization is called [Sophie Germain Identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sophie_Germain_Identity).

Comment: @user31415 But it's older than her.

Comment: @downvoter If something is not clear then please say what that is so that the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you have:
$$x^4-x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-3x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt3 x)^2 $$

and use the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: How did you come up with that? Were you just lucky or there is a method of "fast thinking" :D ?

Comment: This is just from my experience other examples are well known for example $x^4+1$ when we have a polynomial of the form $x^4+ax^2+b$ can be factord using the same method "by completing the square"

Answer (score 4):

You can get it by$$x^4-x^2+1=x^4+2x^2-2x^2-x^2+1=x^4+2x^2+1-3x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt 3x)^2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Take $x^2=t$, and then try to factor the polynomial $t^2-t+1$.