# Is $545^4 + 4^{545}$ a prime number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, exponential-function

The main question is :
Is $545^4 + 4^{545}$ a prime number? Explain your answer.

My approach :
I tried writing the expression as, 
$$545^4 + 4*4^{544}$$
Thus we get,
$$545^4 + 4*{(4^{136})}^4$$

I can't proceed any further. Is there some obvious thing or concept I'm missing? This question is a base-level olympiad question, thus there must be some short solution to this. I will appreciate if you can give a detailed answer, along with a shortcut if you have one, so that I understand the concept thoroughly. Thanks!

Comment: Hint $\ $ **Completing** the square yields a **difference** of squares, [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260952/242)

Comment: @daruma There are at least two errors in your comment. I recommend that you delete it and repost to avoid confusing readers.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Thanks. There is an identity named after Sophie Germain. $x^4+4y^4=x^4+4x^2y^2+4y^4-4x^2y^2=(x^2+2y^2)^2-(2xy)^2$. Then apply difference of two squares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can go through this using primitive steps.
(Proceeding after the two steps given in my approach)
Let $545=x$ and $4^{136}=y$.
Thus, the expression becomes :
$$x^4+4y^4$$
Adding and subtracting by $4x^2y^2$, we get,
$${(x^2+2y^2)}^2-{(2xy)}^2$$
This can be written as :
$$(x^2+2y^2+2xy)(x^2+2y^2-2xy)$$

Now, since there are two factors to the original expression excluding $1$ and itself, the expression $545^4+4^{545}$ is not a prime.

Comment: You need to also show that the second factor, of the form $x^2 + 2y^2 - 2x^2 y^2$, is not equal to $1$ for the particular choice of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Even if it is 1, the other factor itself cannot reduce to $x^4+4y^4$, thus it is surely going to have 3 factors and not be prime. Good enough?

Comment: Same as the comment from @daruma

Comment: @daruma gave me the trick, so I saved everyone else's time by answering my own question.

Comment: @AksharGandhi Note that $5 = 3^2 - 2^2 = (3-2)(3+2)$, but this factorization does not prove $5$ is composite, even though the general statement $a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ is a factorization.  This is why you must take care to establish that both resulting factors are nontrivial.  Incidentally, your factorization should read $$(x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2)(x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2).$$  You've mistakenly squared the $xy$ terms.

Comment: @heropup $x^2-2xy+2y^2=1 \implies x=y \pm \sqrt{1-y^2}$ that is only possible when $-1 \leq y \leq 1$.

Comment: @NgChungTak  Exactly!  That's all you need to justify it, but it still needs to be said.

Comment: Okay @heropup, I get your point, but I don't really understand what to edit in the answer

Comment: @AksharGandhi just argue that $x^2 + y^2 - 2xy \ge 0$, so $x^2 + 2y^2 - 2xy \ge y^2 > 1$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

$$   x^2 - 2 x y + 2 y^2 = (x-y)^2 + y^2 \geq y^2 $$