# Proof for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: 7\mid(1 + 2^{2^n} + 2^{2^{n+1}})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I am stuck at the following exercise:

Prove that
$\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: 7\mid(1 + 2^{2^n} + 2^{2^{n+1}})$.

I tried to prove the Expression by induction but I cannot find a way to prove the implication
$$7\mid(1 + 2^{2^n} + 2^{2^{n+1}}) \Rightarrow 7\mid(1 + 2^{2^{n+1}} + 2^{2^{(n+1)+1}}).$$
Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Your life might be made easier by the observation that 
$$
1 + 2^{2^n} + 2^{2^{n+1}} = \frac{2^{3 \cdot 2^n} - 1}{2^{2^n} - 1}
$$

Comment: Also, what do you know about modular arithmetic?  Have you seen the "phrase" $\pmod 7$?

Comment: Equivalently, examine the difference between $(1 + 2^{2^{n+1}} + 2^{2^{(n+1)+1}})$ and $(1 + 2^{2^{n}} + 2^{2^{n+1}})$.  Is that difference divisible by $7$?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's little theorem.  gcd(2,7) = 1 so $2^6 = 1 \mod 7$. And actually $2^3 = 1 \mod 7$.  So even if you don't know FLT we know $7 = 2^3 - 1$.  Can we prove $(2^3 - 1)$ divides the expression?

Comment: If $7  \mid n$, then $7 \mid {n - 21\,\mathrm{ld}\left(\, n\, \right) \over 10}$ where $\,\mathrm{ld}\left(\, n\, \right)$ is the $last\ digit$ of $n$.

Answer (score 11):

Let $a_n=2^{2^n}$. We have $a_{n+1}=a_n^2$, hence the sequence $\{a_n\pmod{7}\}_{n\geq 0}$ is periodic from some point on. Let we compile a small table:
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline n & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & \ldots  \\ \hline a_n\pmod{7} & 2 & 4 & 2 & 4 & \ldots\\ \hline\end{array}$$
By induction it is trivial that $a_n\equiv 2\pmod{7}$ if $n$ is even and $a_n\equiv 4\pmod{7}$ if $n$ is odd.
In any case,
$$ 1+a_n+a_{n+1} \equiv 1+2+4 \equiv \color{red}{0}\pmod{7} $$
and that proves the claim.

Comment: Why down vote? What is wrong with Jack's answer?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I thought it was good too... probably an error or misunderstanding

Comment: It is from some time on that I continue getting random downvotes, probably revenge downvotes. Annoying for sure.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio They can down vote you but they never can deny the beauty of your solutions.

Comment: @Behrouz I find  $\ 7 = f_0\mid f_1\mid f_2 \cdots\mid f_n $ to be more beautiful (and more simple and far more general) - see my answer. But, of course, beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $1+2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n+1}}=7k$ and set, for simplicity, $a=2^{2^n}$. Then $2^{2^{n+1}}=a^2$ and $2^{2^{n+2}}=a^4$. Then
\begin{align}
&1+2^{2^n}+2^{2^{n+1}}=1+a+a^2 \\[4px]
&1+2^{2^{n+1}}+2^{2^{n+2}}=1+a^2+a^4
\end{align}
Then
$$
(1+a^2+a^4)-(1+a+a^2)=a^4-a=a(a-1)(a^2+a+1)=7ka(a-1)
$$
so
$$
1+a^2+a^4=7k+7ka(a-1)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice $\ \   \overbrace{x^4\!+x^2\!+1}^{\large f_{\Large n+1}} =\, (x^2\!-x+1)\,\overbrace{ (x^2\!+x+1)}^{\large f_{\Large n}} \,\ $ hence $\ f_n\mid f_{n+1}$

therefore by induction: $\ f_0\mid f_n\ $ for all $\ n \ge 0\,\ $ (in your case $\,f_0 = 7)$

---

**Remark** $ $ We can *discover* the factorization in many ways, e.g. by *completing the square* (see comment below), or, more generally, by the [method of simpler multiples](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3224776/242) as below

$$x^2+x+1\,\ {\rm divides}\!\!\!\!\overbrace{\color{#0a0}{x^{\rm\large 2+\color{#c00}3\:\!J}}+x^{\rm\large 1+\color{#c00}3\:\!K}+\color{#90f}{x^{\rm\large \color{#c00}3L^{\phantom{|}}\!}}}^{\textstyle {\rm e.g.}\ \ \color{#0a0}{x^2}\ +\,\ x^4\,\ +\,\ \color{#90f}1\ \ {\rm in\ OP}\, \ \ \ }\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: **Remark** $ $ The factorization arises since [completing the square leads to a difference of squares,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260952/242)  i.e. $$\begin{eqnarray} \color{}{x^4+x^2+1} &\,=\,&\!\!\! \overbrace{\color{}{(x^2\!+1)^2}}^{\rm\!\!\! complete\ the\ \color{}{square}\!\!\!}\!\!\!\!\!-\!\color{#c00}{ x}^2\ \ \text{so, factoring this} \it\text{ difference of squares}\\
 &\,=\,& (x^2+1\color{#c00}\ \ {-\ \ \color{#c00}{x}})\ (x^2+1\, +\, \color{#c00}{x})\\
 \end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

Induction will work here.  Assume $1+2^{2^n} + 2^{2^{n+1}}$ is divisible by 7.
Note that $2^{2^{n+2}} = 2^{2^n4} = 16^{2^n} = (14+2)^{2^n} = 14M+2^{2^n}$ for some integer $M$.  Then $1+2^{2^{n+1}} + 2^{2^{n+2}} = 1+2^{2^{n+1}}+(14+2)^{2^n} = 1+2^{2^{n+1}} +2^{2^n}+14M$, which must be a multiple of 7, since the first three terms are from the induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

The roots of $x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$ are $x=2$ and $x=4$.  If $n$ is odd, then $2^n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, so that $2^{2^n}=2^2=4$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$.  If $n$ is even, then $2^n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, so that $2^{2^n}=2^1=2$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$.