# Prove that $n^4+4$ is composite

Tags: integers

Prove that for all integers $n>1$, $n^4+4$ is composite.

I got $n^4+4=(n^2-2n+2)(n^2+2n+2)$
What should be my next step?

Comment: $n=3 --> 13$ is prime

Comment: $n^4$ or $n^2$? Also please show what you have tried / thought of on the problem.

Comment: If you mean $n^4+4$, just note $n^4+4 = n^4+4n^2+4-4n^2 = (n^2+2)^2-(2n)^2 = (n^2-2n+2)(n^2+2n+2)$

Comment: Lookup the [Sophie Germain Identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sophie_Germain_Identity).

Comment: What means for a number to be composite? (then look back at what you got).

Comment: when is X*Y not composite?

Comment: @Zackkenyon when either $X$ or $Y$ is $1$ or fractional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs are $n\in\Bbb Z, n>1$

Note for $n>1, n\in\Bbb Z, (n^2-2n+2)\ne(n^2+2n+2)$, so there's no way it's a square number,

and that for $n\in \Bbb Z, n^2-2n+2\in\Bbb Z$ and $n^2+2n+2\in \Bbb Z$. So you have two integer factors, both of which are $>1$ for $n>1$, and thus your $n^4+4$ is composite

Answer (score 8):

If you don’t now the factorization of $X^4+4$ as a $\Bbb Z$-polynomial, you’re in good company: Leibniz didn’t, either (or the similar real factorization of $X^4+1$).

This should be taught in high schools:
$$
X^4+4=(X^2-2X+2)(X^2+2X+2)
$$

Comment: It should be taught in high school, but in order to do so you would have to change a lot of other things in the high school math curriculum first.

Comment: Well, if they can teach $X^3-a^3=(X-a)(X^2+aX+a^2)$, which they do, I see no reason why they shouldn’t teach this lonely but beautiful fact.

Comment: @Zackkenyon I've had success teaching this as [completing the square yields a difference of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260952/242), which students find memorable. It also generalizes to completing products.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $n^4+4=(n^2-2n+2)(n^2+2n+2)$. Moreover, $n^2-2n+2=(n-1)^2+1$ and $n^2+2n+2=(n+1)^2+1$; both these integers are greater than $1$ as $n>1$. Thus, $n^4+4$ is a composite number whenever $n>1$.